# Execute a PHP script if a condition is true in WordPress login

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to implement a minor security policy on a WordPress website so I need to be able to call a PHP script from the `wp-login.php` if a certain string is entered on the user input of the login form.

For example: 
If the string `random_pass` is entered to the login form I want to execute the `random.php` from a location on my server.

Is this possible or I need to find an alternative solution ?

Comment: you have to use, this functions but don't know exactly how.
[wp_login](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login), [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `include(path/to/random.php)` or `require(path/to/random.php)` and then a simple if statement

```
if($random_pass){
included_function_in_random.php
}
```